# How to stop Interceptor class rewriting return annotations

Tags: magento2, blocks, interceptor

Magento version: 2.2.3

I have a Block class with a method to fetch the designer associated with a product. It is annotated to return a model interface or null.

```
public function getDesigner(): ?DesignerInterface {
  ...
}
```

When running Magento in production mode, the system compiles an interceptor class for this Block, but drops the `?` in the annotation, resulting in this:

```
public function getDesigner(): DesignerInterface
```

This causes a fatal error on product pages where a product does not have a designer associated with it, as the method no longer accepts `null` as a return value.

First of all, why is Magento modifying my code? This throws a huge red flag for me.

Second, is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later discovered that this is actually caused by a bug in Magento. Details can be found here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15505